# how to form url in prisma.schema file using system variable

Tags: prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      =  "postgresql://${app_db_username}:${app_db_password}@${endpoint}/${dbname}?schema=public"
}
```

I'm trying to form the below url, so how to use it

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is [not implemented](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2559) in Prisma yet. As of now you need to provide an environment variable that contains full database url:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

You can use an `.env` file to [prepare](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema#accessing-environment-variables-from-the-schema) the environment variable (Prisma v2.7.0+):

```
# .env
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://${app_db_username}:${app_db_password}@${endpoint}/${dbname}?schema=public
```